# How to boot window from recovery partition?

Tags: boot

Acer Service Center created recovery discs for my Acer laptop. And they also created a partition in which contains the data from recovery discs. I can see that partition from Disk Management inside of Windows only. But how do I boot from it? Some months ago, I had Linux installed. So when the laptop boots up, I can see that partition, but not now. How can I boot from it? I can't see that drive when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

```
F2 = enter BIOS setup
F8 = Boot in safe mode
F12 = choose the boot drive
```

Answer (score 1):

Acer computers use a partition on the hard drive to house the Acer system recovery program. You can use this recovery program to create recovery discs for your computer or for applications and drivers. It can also recover or reinstall the operating system directly from the hard drive, restoring your Acer system to its out-of-the-box condition. Booting from the recovery partition on your Acer computer is easy.

The First Step:

Reboot or turn on your Acer computer.

The Second Step:

Press the "Alt" and "F10" keys together repeatedly when the Acer logo appears on the screen. Rather than booting to Windows, your computer will boot from the partition on the hard drive that contains the Acer recovery program. If a Windows screen does appear, press "Enter."

The Third Step:

Use the Acer recovery program to reinstall or recover the Windows operating system, reinstall the drivers and applications that came with your computer or create a factory recovery disc or a drivers and applications disc.